# How I can get a click event

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Hello I have bind some HTML elements. Take a look at below code

```
<DIV ng-bind-html-unsafe="myHTML"></DIV>
```

In controller code is

```
$scope.myHTML="<DIV ng-click="myFunc()"></DIV>"
$scope.myFunc= function(){
alert("TEST");
}
```

here my html is correctly loaded. When I click on the div I am not able to get an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` does not support directive. We have to somehow compile the bound html.

Try compiling it by writing a directive:

```
app.directive("compile",function($compile,$timeout){
    return {
       priority:-1,
       link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
         $timeout(function(){
           $compile(element.contents())(scope);
         });

       }
    }
});
```

Use it:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="myHTML" compile></div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUj5jYRtYiASwrUFTR3L?p=preview)

Another solution is writing our own ng-bind-html

```
app.directive("myNgBindHtml",function($compile){
    return {
       link:function(scope, element, attrs) {

         scope.$watch(attrs.myNgBindHtml,function(value){
           element.html(value);
           $compile(element.contents())(scope);
         })
       }
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5Sit07sxpiiprTX5utJ?p=preview)

Comment: it gives me following error 
Uncaught Error: selectors not implemented

Comment: is there any solution in angular js. 
i have tried to comile it in below format
$scope.myHTML = $compile($scope.myHTML)($scope);
Its give me output on div as below 
[[object HTMLDivElement]]

Comment: @Shardul Pendse: I figured out a solution that works, we have to write another directive to compile it.

Comment: hello @KhanhTO thanks for the solution. In my side i fetching the data from DB and then prepared  a string of  in HTML and then binding it. So how when I console the element.contents(); it is blank. So is there any solution like a call back?? Meaning after the contents are bind then can we call directive.

Comment: @KhanhTO when I put console.log(element.contents()) in example given by you it prints some objects are bind. How we can figure it out?

Comment: @Shardul Pendse: in fact, in the first solution, when you call `console.log(element.contents())`, the objects are not bound yet. But because `console.log` is live and passed a reference, it will update the console immediately when the element.contents() changes. Try using alert you will see a different

Comment: @Shardul Pendse: I agree that using a callback is a good solution. When I was trying to work out a solution for this question, I also thought about that. I did not figure out how to do that. Using $timeout in this case is not so good, but i think works because the event will be scheduled for the next cycle. I also used `priority:-1` to ensure this is the last directive to run

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code:

```
$scope.myHTML="<DIV ng-click="myFunc()"></DIV>"
```

You should use single quotes around `myFunc()`, like this:

```
$scope.myHTML="<DIV ng-click='myFunc()'></DIV>"
```